# Jboss Fuse 6.2.1 Missing jar org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javassist

Tags: jbossfuse

I'm trying to deploy a bundle in Fuse 6.2.1-084 but it fails because of a ClassNotFoundException

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
```

The class is required by this other bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections:0.9.8_1

The same bundle was deploying and working correctly on Fuse 6.2.0-133.
I updated the pom of the project to use the lib version of Fuse 6.2.1.

What I've noticed is that the lib supposed to provide the missing class was in the "system" folder of Fuse 6.2.0 but it is not in Fuse 6.2.1

The lib is org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javassist

My question is: the lib was removing for a reason or it is a bug? If it is not a bug, do I have to explicity include the bundle in the fabric profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing class is contained in this bundle, under

> jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133/system

```
[vgohel@localhost system]$ jar -tf org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar|grep ClassFile
javassist/bytecode/ClassFile.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFilePrinter.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFileWriter$AttributeWriter.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFileWriter$ConstPoolWriter.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFileWriter$FieldWriter.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFileWriter$MethodWriter.class
javassist/bytecode/ClassFileWriter.class
```

Please install the bundle as,

> install -s mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA

before you install your custom bundle
or use

> dynamic-import

**The version of the jar in fuse version 6.2.0 and 6.2.1 are the same.**

Comment: Thanks, it works using the org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA bundle.